# MySQL one row of sum after limited results

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

I've got this `User` table:

```
+----------+-------+
| Username | Value |
+----------+-------+
| User4    |     2 |
| User1    |     3 |
| User3    |     1 |
| User2    |     6 |
| User4    |     2 |
+----------+-------+
```

And I do this query to get the top 2's sums:

```
SELECT Username, SUM(Value) AS Sum
FROM User
GROUP BY Username
ORDER BY Sum DESC
LIMIT 0, 2
```

Which gives me as a result:

```
+----------+-----+
| Username | Sum |
+----------+-----+
| User2    |   6 |
| User4    |   4 |
+----------+-----+
```

What I'm looking for is **one more row giving the sum of all the values**, like:

```
+----------+-----+
| Username | Sum |
+----------+-----+
| User2    |   6 |
| User4    |   4 |
| All      |  14 |
+----------+-----+
```

**Is there any way to achieve that?** Preferably with no procedures.

Comment: GROUP BY Username WITH ROLLUP

Comment: I didn't know `WITH ROLLUP`. It's so handy... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`WITH ROLLUP`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Username, 'All'), SUM(Value) AS Sum
FROM User
GROUP BY Username WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY Sum DESC
```

or, if you want just top 2 along with the sum of *all*:

```
 SELECT Username, s
 FROM (
    SELECT Username, s
    FROM (
      SELECT COALESCE(Username, 'All') AS Username, SUM(Value) AS s
      FROM User
      GROUP BY Username WITH ROLLUP  ) AS t
    ORDER BY s DESC      
    LIMIT 0, 3) AS s
 ORDER BY IF(Username = 'All', 0, s) DESC
```

Comment: What is the advantage over the Union All (the other answer)?

Comment: @ErdalG. It should perform better as the table is queried once. But you can tell us how both queries compare when acted upon your actual data.

Comment: It works as a charm. I like this answer as you don't have to duplicate the query like the other answer. Duplicating the query is REALLY annoying when queries get bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Use union

```
SELECT Username, SUM(Value) AS Sum
FROM User
GROUP BY Username
ORDER BY Sum DESC
LIMIT 0, 2
union 
SELECT'ALL', SUM(Value) AS Sum
FROM User
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a UNION ALL to do that.

```
(SELECT Username, SUM(Value) AS Sum
FROM User
GROUP BY Username
ORDER BY Sum DESC
LIMIT 0, 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'All', SUM(Value) AS Sum FROM User)
```

Comment: "Best" answer (so far).

Comment: @RickJames I've just tested it: it's the same speed as WITH ROLLUP but when you have a bigger query this gets huge (you have to duplicate the query basically). So, why is this one the "best answer so far"?

Comment: Shortest, and seems to get 'right' answer.  Is it 'right' but slower?